# Coding for multiple regression

Tags: r

I have a data frame in which I have several columns and rows. For example the data frame below shows column 1 to 4 is my soil moisture data, 5 to 8 is evapotranspiration (`ET`), and column 9 to 12 is precipitation data (`p`). I have 156 Colum of soil moisture, `ET`, `P`. Now I want to run a multiple linear regression with column of soil moisture to the respective column of precipitation and evapotranspiration where my soil moisture is a dependent variable and `ET` and `P` is independent variable. I want to use the following equation for my independent variable while running the multiple regression and calculate the coefficients like `a1`, `a2` and `b1`, `b2`.

```
ΔΦ(j.t+1) = a1P(j.t) + a2P(J.t-1) + b1ET(j.t) + b2ET(J.t-1)+εt+1
```

where `Δθ(j,t+1)` is the soil moisture difference between `t` and `t+1`, `a` and `b` are coefficients to be determined for precipitation (`P`), and evapotranspiration (`ET`), and `εt+1` is the error term of the model.

My data frame looks like:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

NA NA NA NA NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NA NA NA NA 645 732 1010 1050 169.7152863 264.919281 174.5597839 117.1220169 1.788969846 1.769300308 1.881795708 1.798497618 NaN NaN NaN NaN 183.5778961 272.1306458 164.4124298 94.27450562 3.41084 3.41084 NA NA 576 657 840 817 166.3976135 263.9378357 161.8202972 97.60928345 1.995551665 2.037976549 2.144578129 2.065179551 533 597 747 744 151.7550201 265.6147766 155.722702 91.79171753

I used the following codes to create data frame and matrix so far in R programming language and want further help to complete the task please.

```
data = read.table('MasterPiece.csv',header=TRUE, sep=',')
SMDI = data.frame(data1[3:158])      #Soil moisture
MODET = data.frame(data[159:314])    #Evapotranspiration
PRCP = data.frame(data[315:470])     #Precipitation
smdi1 = data.matrix(SMDI)
modet1 = data.matrix(MODET)
prcp1 = data.matrix(PRCP)
```

Answer (score 0):

The linear regression function, `lm()` takes the following arguments:

```
lm(dependentVariable ~ independentVariable1 + independentVariable2, data = df)
```

Others might be able to point out a way around it, but I think this means all your variables (columns) must be in one data frame. So, your first line is fine:

```
data <- read.table("MasterPiece.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

(Note: it's recommended to use `<-` instead of `=` when assigning). You do not need to put your variables in separate data frames.

If, for example, your variable names are: `smdi1`..., `modet1`..., `prcp1`... you can run your model with:

```
m1 <- lm(smdi1 ~ modet1 + prcp1, data = data)
summary(m1)
```